# MDX expression for aggregation by SUM of one level above lowest?

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I have two dimensions A,B and a measure M which is aggregated by summing.

If I would apply both dimensions I could get a table that might look as follows:

[image]

Now the problem I am facing is that I would like to sum column-wise (or row-wise) so I can calculate the column-wise ratio of a value:

[image]

I tried expressions like `[Measures].[M] / SUM([Measures].[M])` or `[Measures].[M] / ([All], [Measures].[M])` - to no avail.

I would like to add that the formula should be dynamic and not use a specific drill down.
Expressed in words - the denominator should be the sum of the measure if the drill down would lack the last step.

I'm using Mondrian 4.6 BTW which is not fully compatible to MDX for that version.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
With 
  SET ROWSET as [Dimension 1].[Some Level].Members
  SET COLSET as [Dimension 2].[Other Level].Members

  MEMBER [Measures].[Total] as Aggregate( ROWSET, [Measures].[M] )
  MEMBER [Measures].[Ratio] as [Measures].[M] / [Measures].[Total]

Select
  ROWSET on Rows,
  COLSET * { [Measures].[M], [Measures].[Ratio] } on Columns

From [My Cube]
```

Your query parameters would be used on the definition of ROWSET and COLSET only.

To get the total by Rows just replace ROWSET by COLSET on the total definition,

Comment: I doubt this is going to do the trick for me because your solution depends on specifying the dimensions. But I'll give it a try.

Comment: Dont't forget to support BI.stackexchange.com: http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/a-stackoverflow-but-for-business-intelligence/